# How to write a readable csv file after api paginated loop in python

Tags: python, api, loops, csv

Im having troubles writing the output of my api call loop to a readable csv file.
Im quite new to python and its probably because of the different data formats.
The csv only contains 9 columns, it does not read all the other elements as separate columns

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

FileNaam = 'name'
   
params = (
    ('api_key', 'api_key'),
    ('since', '1595590000'),
    ('sort', 'asc')
)
url = 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline'
discover_api = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    
events = discover_api["data"]
next_id = discover_api["next"]

continueloop = 1

while continueloop ==1:
    params = (
        ('api_key', 'api_key'),
        ('since', next_id),
        ('sort', 'asc')
    )
    discover_apiloop = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    events.extend(discover_apiloop["data"])
    if discover_apiloop["next"] is None:
        continueloop = 0
    else:
        next_id = discover_apiloop["next"]
  
data = json.dumps(events, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

df = pd.read_json(data)
df.to_csv(FileNaam+'.csv')
```

When Im not looping but only performing one api call Im using different formats and the csv is good. So the code below is working properly but I want the same result when using the loop.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

FileNaam = 'name'

params = (
    ('api_key', 'api_key'),
    ('sort', 'asc'),
    ('since', '1595590000')
)

response = requests.get('https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline', params=params)

responsetext = response.text
data = json.loads(responsetext)
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])
df.to_csv(FileNaam +'.csv')
```

How to a transform my output to get the proper csv?

Comment: if you run in loop then inside loop `append()` data to list - and later convert this list to pandas or directly save in file.

Comment: I can't run it but as for me you should create list with first result `events = [ discover_api["data"] ]` - to create first row in this list/table - and later `append()` new results  `events.append( discover_apiloop["data"] )` to create new rows in this list/table. Using `expand` you probably only add new elements to first row.

Comment: Thnx for your response, got a csv but  the arrangement of the objects over columns wasnt still not going well. Finally got it work using the json_normalize after the loop

Answer (score 1):

Got it work using the json_normalize after the loop

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

bestandsNaam = 'name'

params = (
    ('api_key', 'api_key'),
    ('since', '1595650000'),
    ('sort', 'asc')
)
url = 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline'
discover_api = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

events = discover_api["data"]
next_id = discover_api["next"]

continueloop = 1

while continueloop ==1:
    params = (
        ('api_key', 'api_key'),
        ('since', next_id),
        ('sort', 'asc')
    )
    discover_apiloop = requests.get('https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline', params=params).json()
    events.extend(discover_apiloop["data"])
    if discover_apiloop["next"] is None:
        continueloop = 0
    else:
        next_id = discover_apiloop["next"]

df = pd.json_normalize(events)
df.to_csv(bestandsNaam+'.csv')
```

Comment: instead of `while continueloop ==1:` you can use `while True:` and later use `break` to exit this loop - `if discover_apiloop["next"] is None: break` . But if still you want to use `continueloop` then value `True/False` will be more readable then `1/0` - `continueloop = True` and `while continueloop:` and later `if ...: continueloop = False`

Answer (score -3):

I am trying todo pagination in Klaviyo and data seems to coming, can you please let me know whether pagination is done correctly or not?

import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
url = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline"
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime, time

midnight = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time.min)
from datetime import timedelta

yesterday_midnight = midnight - timedelta(days=1)

yesteday_epoch = str(int((yesterday_midnight).timestamp()))
print(yesteday_epoch)
querystring = {"api_key":"API_KEY","since":yesteday_epoch,"count":"100","sort":"desc"}

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

output_data_list = response.json()['data']

next_page = response.json()['next']

got_next = True
while(got_next):
url = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v1/metrics/timeline"
querystring = {"api_key":"pk_API_Key","since":next_page,"count":"100","sort":"desc"}

```
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

output_data_list = response.json()['data']
if(next_page):
    with open("pagination1/metrics_{}.json".format(next_page),"a") as f: 
                for i in output_data_list:          
                        f.write(json.dumps(i)+"\n")

if next_page is None:
    got_next = False
else:
    next_page = response.json()['next']
    got_next = False
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30353055)